# Order of a cyclic group with a single proper subgroup of order 7

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups, cyclic-groups

> Let $G$ be a cyclic group with its only proper subgroup of order 7. Find out the order of the group.

let the subgroup of order 7 be denoted by H. since 7 is prime H is cyclic. Now if G =  then H= for some r in Z. There can be two cases 1. x belongs to H 2. x dose not belong to H.Now if x belongs to H  then x = (x$^r$)$^k$ where k<7 ....I need some help here.

Comment: your first statement in second paragraph should be something like "$G$ is cyclic and $H\leq G$ implies$H$ is cyclic"... you said "Now if $G=$" what is it equal to?

Comment: Since 7 is prime H is cyclic

Comment: I said you dont have to use order of $H$ that is just to make it simple...

Comment: So how to solve it?

Comment: Can $G$ be of order $21$?... $14$?

Comment: That is obvious ... order of G is a multiple of 7. But anything more specific?

Comment: That is what you have to think about.... Suppose $|G|=14$ you would have an element of order $(??)$ this contradicts "only proper subgroup" condition... suppose you have $|G|=21$ then?

Comment: Sorry for the nonsense. Got exam tomm. tension talking. Thank you very much

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $p$ is a prime divisor of $|G|$ then by Cauchy theorem there is a subgroup $H$ of order $p$.

So in your case $|G| = 7^{n}$, $n \geq 1.$

But $G$ is cyclic, so for every divisor d of $|G|$ there is an unique subgroup of order d $\Rightarrow |G| = 7^{2}$.

Answer (score 1):

$G$ is isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}$ and the subgroups of $G$ are in bijection with the divisors of $n$. Therefore $n$ has only $7$ as a proper divisor. What is the only value of $n$ for this to happen?